# Create virtual directory on same azure web app

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an application running on Azure, what I need is to have the application copied so different users can access for example site.com/s1 and site.com/s2 and use them as separate. The application is the same, the database will change.

I tried to create a virtual directory for my app but I get the same error every time: "The physical path for virtual path '/s1' is invalid."

I tried creating a physical directory from FTP and I can see the new directory, but Azure don't recognize it as a physical one.

I would like to have wwwroot/s1 wwwroot/s2 and access those apps the way I explained before.

[image: I'm creating the virtual directory from the management portal like you see in the image.]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please have a try to config the Virtual directory `site/test1` on the Azure portal as following screenshot

[image]

When we push the WebApp to the Azure, we need to include the virtual directory path in the Site Name and Destination URL sections on the Connection tab

[image]

After that we can visit the WebApp with sitename/site1

[image]

We also can check the uploaded file from Azure Kudu tool (https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell)

[image]

Comment: This solution is possible if you are using the windows environment for your app service. Is there a concept of a virtual directory when you use a Linux environment? I don't see similar options when creating a Linux based App Service on Azure. Any pointers?