# I have copied files via FileZilla to Azure but the index page doesn't show

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I shall try not to be subjective so as not be closed.

This is my first foray into Azure and it really is NOT like my dedicated server on another hosting company. Suffice it to say, what takes me minutes to deploy a site via FTP, then to IIS to set it up, has taken me WEEKS!

I don't want to set up any of the "pre-packaged" Quickstart solutions. I simply want my INDEX.HTML file to DISPLAY.

I copied all the files via Filezilla to Azure, quite easily, but yet, when I go to the URL, I keep getting:

```
Your App Service app has been created

Go to your app's Quick Start guide in the Azure portal to get started or read our deployment documentation.
```

Everything is set up on Azure perfectly.

Here's what it looks like under the appSettings Tab:

```
**Virtual applications and directories**

/                     site\wwwroot                     Application …
/wwwroot              site\wwwroot\mynewsite           Application …
```

The directory, site\wwwroot\mynewsite has an index.html but it will not display when I type in the URL.

I already built the site and the company I'm working for wants it on AZURE.

A dedicated server takes under 15 min. This has taken weeks.

UPDATE:

Thiago, thank you... so here's the file structure below...

[image]

Reveals EXACTLY what my directory looks like. Under /thingblugrow is where "the fake name" mynewsite exists. I thought it'd be easier to just show you what I really have.

So, /thingblugrow has an index.html file....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your want to visit http://yoursitename.azurewebsites.net/mynewsite/index.html,

The appsetting we need config it as following in your case:

**Virtual applications and directories**

```
/                     site\wwwroot                     Application …
/mynewsite            site\wwwroot\thingblugrow        Application …
```

You also can refer to another [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073570/create-virtual-directory-on-same-azure-web-app/43075215#43075215) to get more info about creating Virtual applications and directories

Comment: Tom, thanks. I just wanted to know, can the /mynewsite name be like this?  /thingblugrow???

Comment: if you change the from  `/mynewsite`  to `/thingblugrow`, then we need to visit with http://yoursitename.azurewebsites.net/thingblugrow/index.html.

Comment: Tom, one more thing.  I've attached a domain, omnigrow.com to that directory. So, if I punch up: omnigrow.com, I will see my page and secondly, I won't have to do. thingblugrow.azurewebsites.net/mynewsite, as in your example, correct?

Comment: It should be that, but I haven't tested. If any issue about custom domain, please have a look to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name), or you can open another SO thread to get more help from global communities if you have any other questions .

Comment: Tom, you and the rest of the SO Community are the best. We are ALL A TEAM. There's no "I" in TEAM.  Thiago, your answer was good as well. Combined, I think I have a handle on this. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding an extra level, so in your case you'll be able to see the index through:

http://yoursitename.azurewebsites.net/mynewsite/index.html

Just move all the content from "mynewsite" folder to the parent directory (wwwroot).

[image]

Comment: Thiago, thank you. SEE UPDATE ABOVE and let me know if that helps more...

Comment: I just tried that and get: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Thiago, wait, I have the actual DOMAIN pointed (externally) from another hosting company back to, Azure as a Custom domain. PLUS, there's an SSL (uploaded a PFX file) attached to the domain. Then I saw that using custom domains on Azure does not allow SSL.  The inside of the azure site, points to the domain, not the extended domainname.azurewebsites.net/mynewsite.  It's actually: domainname.com/....

Comment: Please check Tom's answer. You just need to create a virtual directory. It should work.