# Multiple App services to use the same domain name

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

we have a scenario where we have multiple azure app services where we have our Web APIs deployed . however we need all the app services to use the same domain name (not sub domains) e.g 
http://example.com/api1 on one app service and http://example.com/api2 on other app service. 
we have looked at using application gateway but it seems that URL rewriting is not supported yet. is there a anyway to achieve this without using third party components?

Thanks

Comment: Is it acceptable to use Azure virtual  directory? If it is acceptable,more detail please refer to the [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/). You also could refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073570/create-virtual-directory-on-same-azure-web-app?answertab=active#tab-top).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean URL routing or rewriting (rewriting as in `mod_rewrite`)?

URL-based routing [is fully supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-url-route-overview) in Azure Application Gateway.

[image: URL routing]

[image: Rule example]

Comment: would this support using multiple app services and point to the same domain i.e. for http://example.com/api1 direct to http://epi1.azurewebsites.net app service and for http://example.com/api2 direct to http://epi2.azurewebsites.net app service

Comment: Yes indeed, that's what it's for.