# Deployment of EmberJS frontend application

Tags: azure, ember.js, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

I have planned to separate my application in two layers. One will be the API Rest layer, backed by Ruby and another the frontend, using EmberJS, both in Azure Cloud.

For the API layer, it's fine, we going to use the Azure Web App, which is a container based with Ruby installed.

But for the frontend I'm not sure.

One way is use the Web App based on NodeJS, but, the EmberJS files should be served as static way, so I'm considering to deploy it on Azure Blob Storage, instead.

For deployment it's necessary a NodeJS server? As far as I know we only use NodeJS utilities such as NPM for packet management, but not to serve the application.

Anyone could give me a light on it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your application written in .NET, Node.js, Python or PHP that hosted on Azure App Services (Windows platform) is running on Microsoft IIS.
Azure App Services can handle these languages correctly because it already has the runtimes installed and has corresponded CGI handler set in the IIS configuration file called `web.config`. If you don't have any CGI configuration in it then Azure will serve all your application files as static content as well.

So, in this case, you'd need to [build the Ember.js App](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/getting-started/quick-start/#toc_building-for-production) in your local with the command `ember build --env production` and then put all built files to IIS's virtual directory `D:\home\site\wwwroot` in Azure.

See also:

- [Create a static HTML web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-html)

Comment: We would like to have a separately endpoint, since our backend is an API app. In that case I just need any way to serve statically the EmberJS files, right?

Comment: Yes, for a separate endpoint, you need to create a new app service.

Comment: Or [Create virtual directory on same azure web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073570/create-virtual-directory-on-same-azure-web-app).

Comment: The last one is more suitable. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The question is a broad ask not suitable for StackOverFlow,

Simple answer would be to use Azure App Services and host both your frontend on nodejs or ASP.NET core and backend ruby as now we support Linux Containers.

Check this blog on how to create your Ruby backend : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-ruby

Check this blog on how to create frontend app : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs

It doesn't matter what you use for EmberJs both Node and ASP.NET core provide excellent support for developing any frontend apps easily. Personally I prefer ASP.NET Core here is the video tutorial to get you started : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAMuo6K7VcE

Comment: Thank your for your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

In the backend I used the WebApp and for the front-end we use Azure Blob, since the EmberJS will host static content, using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-deploy-azure-blob.
It worked very well :D, now Azure Blobs is able to configure default documents, such as index.html, pretty same the AWS S3, finally.