# How can I add an MVC project along side an already hosted web api on Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an azure mobile app backend on azure that my Xamarin Form app interacts with. I also have a single index.html file that is rendered on the actual site.  However, based on some upcoming requirements, i think i'll need to add an MVC app for the frontend and just keep the azure mobile app for the backend.

I've looked through a couple of options so far. *This is a fake URL

---

### Create a virtual directory for the azure mobile app backend (i.e. www.blahblah.com/Services) and host the MVC project at the root

- I would love to go this route, however, I think when I add this as a
  virtual directory, it'll change the URL of my service
  (www.blahblah.com/api/etc to www.blahblah.com/Services/api/etc) that my app hits and may potentially cause
  some down time while i update the iOS and Android app and force the
  user to update the app in order for it to work.  Is there a way I can
  do this without causing downtime?

### Convert the Azure Mobile App backend to an MVC project with API built in

- I've looked into this but there doesn't seem to be much info on converting an Azure Mobile App into an MVC Project. My mobile app backend doesn't have a global.asax and it didn't wouldn't even let me register MVC routing (couldn't find the reference) to test this on my own.

### Make my Azure Mobile App backend mimic an MVC project

- I have less research here so I'm not sure if this is even a possibility to make my single-file site act like an MVC site with routing.

---

I think I lean more towards creating a virtual directory for my backend so I'd be interested to know if I can make this work without affecting my api URL or without creating any downtime.

---

### Update

One thing i've noticed is that I can create a virtual directory for my mobile service backend and it will hit the api with or without the name of the virtual directory in the URL (localhost:49999/Services/api and localhost:49999/api) Does this mean this would also work if I create a virtual directory on Azure and push this project there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073570/create-virtual-directory-on-same-azure-web-app) answer. There's been some changes as far as the portal goes. To add virtual directories via the portal, click Path Mappings from the Configuration blade.

[image]